# WINDOW_AUTOSIZE in namedWindow() method

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

I want to enable the user to  be able to draw rectangles and define regions in the image window. The trouble is that the image has to strictly be of A4 size dimensions which is why I have used the WINDOW_AUTOSIZE mode while calling namedWindow. But this seems to mess up the points P1 and P2 that are used to make the rectangle. This somehow doesn't happen with WINDOW_NORMAL mode.

Here is the code:
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

```
cv::Point P1;
cv::Point P2;
Mat temp;

void CallBack(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* userdata) {
    if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN) {
        P1.x = x;
        P1.y = y;
    }
    else if(event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP) {
        P2.x = x;
        P2.y = y;
        rectangle(temp, P1, P2, Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    temp = imread("template.png");
    namedWindow("Templating", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Templating", temp);
    cv::setMouseCallback("Templating", CallBack, NULL);
    waitKey(0);
    imshow("Templating", temp);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you mean by "mess up the points"? Please elaborate, and if possible provide a concrete example.

Comment: Why are you calling imshow() and waitkey() twice?